# Prove that the map $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ given $f(t)=1/2(e^t+e^{-t},e^t-e^{-t})$ is an embedding

Tags: numerical-methods, manifolds, graphing-functions, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm not able to prove that the below map is embedding.

Prove that the map $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given $f(t)=1/2(e^t+e^{-t},e^t-e^{-t})$ is an embedding and $M=f(R)$ is a $1$-manifold and graph it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You have( see [hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function))
$$
f(t)=\left(\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2},\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2} \right)= (\cosh t,\sinh t)
$$

and, since $\cosh^2 t-\sinh^2 t=1$ this is  the [parametric equation of an hyperbola.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Parametric_representation_with_hyperbolic_sine.2Fcosine)